# How to subtract only selected value from Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic, formik

Hello here is my problem, I have implemented a table that table fill when I choose some suggestion. The table contains three columns of (product, qty, balance and add button) So when I click add button it displays some popup form.

[image]

[image]

So I want to do when adding some quantity in the popup menu and after that click the add button it will reduce from the balance field in the table according to the selected product. Below is the table array.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import {
  Grid,
  Table,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  Paper,
  TableBody, 
  Button 
} from "@material-ui/core"
import AddItem from "./AddItem"
import { useStyles } from "../../../../styles/classes"

export default function ItemsList({
  cart,
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  values,
  setFieldValue,
  volumes
}) {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState("")
  const [factoryId, setFactoryId] = useState("")
 
  const handleClickOpen = (productId, factoryId) => {
    setProductId(productId)
    setFactoryId(factoryId)
    setOpen(true)
  }

  const handleClose = (value) => {
    setOpen(false)   
  }

  const addToList = (factory) => {
    setOpen(false)

    const product = cart.find(
      (item) => item.productId === Number(productId)
    )
  
    
    const item = {
      productId: productId,
      productName: product.productName,
      containerNo: values.containerNo,
      sealNo: values.sealNo,
      qty: values.qty,
      factoryId: factory.id,
      factory: factory.name,
      printDate: values.printDate,
      printTime: values.printTime,
      palletNo: values.palletNo,  
      

    }

    const idx = values.volumes.findIndex(e=>e.number === Number(values.noOfContainers))
    console.log(idx)
    const current = values.volumes[idx].data;
    current.push(item)
    
    setFieldValue(`volumes[${idx}].data`,current)  

    //sum of qty in loaded volumes for this product

    values.invoiceItems.forEach((item, idx) => {
      item.balance = (Number(item.balance) - Number(values.qty))
    })

    setFieldValue('invoiceItems', values.invoiceItems)   

  }

  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <Grid item md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
      <TableContainer component={Paper} >
        <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="left">Product</TableCell>          
              <TableCell align="left">Quantity</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Balance</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Add</TableCell>             
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {cart.map((row, i) => (
              <TableRow key={i}>
                <TableCell align="left">{row.productName}</TableCell>             
                <TableCell align="left">{row.qty}</TableCell>       
                <TableCell align="left">{row.balance}</TableCell>                
                <TableCell align="left">
                  <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    size="small"
                    color="secondary"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleClickOpen(row.productId)
                    }}>
                    add
                  </Button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>

      <AddItem
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleBlur={handleBlur}
        values={values}
        addToList={addToList}
        volumes={volumes}
      />
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

```
import React, { useState} from "react"
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardActions,
  Button,
  CardHeader, 
} from "@material-ui/core"
import Alert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert"
import axios from 'axios'
//validation
import { Formik, Form } from "formik"
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import { useStyles } from "../../../styles/classes"


import ItemList from "./subComponents/ItemsList"
import MetaData from "./subComponents/MetaData"
import ContainerList from "./subComponents/ContainerList"
import {useInitialValues} from '../../../hooks/useLoadingInfoData'

 // validation schema
 let validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  volumes: Yup.string().required(),

})



export default function LoadingInfo(props) {
  const classes = useStyles() 
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useInitialValues()
  const [volumes, setVolumes] = useState([])

  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
    showAlert: false,
    severity: "success",
    message: "",
  })


   // create method
   const submit = async (e, { resetForm }) => {
    try {
      await axios.post("/loadingInfo", e)
      resetForm()
      setAlert({
        showAlert: true,
        severity: "success",
        message: "Loading Information created successfully!",
      })
    } catch (error){
      if (error.response.status === 422) {
        setAlert({
          showAlert: true,
          severity: 'error',
          message: 'Loading information already exists!',
        })
      } else {
        setAlert({
          showAlert: true,
          severity: 'error',
          message: 'Loading information creation failed!',
        })
      }
    } 
  }

   
  return (
   
    <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={1}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          onSubmit={submit}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          enableReinitialize>
          {({
            isValid,
            dirty,
            values,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            setFieldValue,
            errors,
          }) => {
            return (
              <Form>
                <Card variant="outlined" style={{marginBottom: '1rem'}}>
                  <CardHeader title="Loading Information"></CardHeader>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                      <MetaData
                        values={values}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        setAlert={setAlert}
                        setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                      />                     
                      <ItemList
                        cart={values.invoiceItems}
                        values={values}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                        volumes={volumes}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                  </CardContent>                 
                </Card>
                <Card variant="outlined">                 
                  <CardContent>
                  {values.volumes.map( (data , idx) => 
                    <ContainerList values={data}  idx={idx}  setFieldValue={setFieldValue}/>  
                  )}             
                                  
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                  <Button 
                      variant="contained" 
                      color="primary" 
                      type="submit"  
                      disabled={!dirty || !isValid}>
                    create
                  </Button>
                   
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Form>
            )
          }}
        </Formik>
      </Grid>
      <Grid></Grid>
      {alert.showAlert && (
        <Grid item md={12}>
          <Alert
            severity={alert.severity}
            onClose={() =>
              setAlert({
                ...alert,
                showAlert: false,
              })
            }>
            {alert.message}
          </Alert>
        </Grid>
      )}
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

Comment: So is the issue is how to call `setFieldValue` in `addToList` with updated state? It seems you are just mutating the `values` prop object with the `values.invoiceItems.forEach` function. Can you share the parent component providing the props?

Comment: Hello, @DrewReese I had put the parent component.